# Is there any way to prevent Outlook from disabling addins?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I developed an addin for Outlook 365 with C# .net4.5 VSTO. Users complain that Outlook disables the plugin because it slows down its launch. The plugin at Outlook startup does nothing, not even in the ribbon load. Reading the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/support-for-keeping-add-ins-enabled) to avoid disabling the plugin you need to create two registry keys below

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Resiliency\AddinList --> key "<Prog-ID of Addin>" string value "1"
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Resiliency\DoNotDisableAddinList --> key "<Prog-ID of Addin>" dword_32bit value 1
```

I tried to create them but Outlook keeps disabling addins. Is there any way to prevent Outlook from disabling addins?

Thanks

Comment: What about the bullet list under [System administrator control over add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/support-for-keeping-add-ins-enabled#preventing-add-ins-from-being-disabled)? Only two of them are relevant to startup.

Comment: hi @nilsK, i have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons why your add-in could be disabled. One of them is exceptions at runtime. In that case (if it throws exceptions at runtime) your add-in will be disabled anyway. So, I'd suggest excluding most-spreaded factors first.

Typically you need to add a new key with a ProgID of the add-in set to 1 which stands to always enabled. For example, I've found this image while searching over the internet:

[image: prevent add-in from being disabled]

But anyway I'd recommend optimizing your add-in as the [Preventing add-ins from being disabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/support-for-keeping-add-ins-enabled#preventing-add-ins-from-being-disabled) section states.